# Block entire sections of HTML in jade/pug instead of individual lines

Tags: html, pug

In Jade/Pug you can render out raw HTML with pipe

```
| <div>some stuff</div>
```

Is there an effective way if you need to block out hundreds of lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use a period at the end of the parent tag.  This is used a lot with `script` elements:

```
script.
  (type as many Javascript lines as you want here)
```

Look under the header "Block in a Tag" in the [Plain Text documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html)